# Does Three.js support OES_texture_float?

Tags: floating-point, three.js, textures, webgl-extensions

I want to render position or depth to a floating texture. 
I use

```
vsnTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight,
            { minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat ,type:THREE.FloatType });
```

as the render target.

Then, I tested

```
var gl = this.renderer.getContext();
    if( !gl.getExtension( "OES_texture_float" ) ){
        console.error( "No OES_texture_float support for float textures!" );
    }
```

and found no error. Chrome supports OES_texture_float, and I step into THREE.js:

```
_gl.texImage2D( _gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, glFormat, renderTarget.width, renderTarget.height, 0, glFormat, glType, null );
 //console.log(glType);
```

I found glType =5126(gl.FLOAT) ,when I set the WebGLRenderTarget:type:THREE.FloatType. This means I could use OES_texture_float. Do I have something wrong? Because whatever I set the type:THREE.FloatType or use the default ( THREE.UnsignedByteType), I both get the same render texture. 
Am I not using the `OES_texture_float` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. This example shows how to use it:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds

Comment: Thanks, @mrdoob I use the example from https://github.com/arose/arose.github.io/blob/master/demo/oit/examples/webgl_oit.html. I set the renderTarget gl.type. When debug into THREE.js, I add console.log(glType) in this.setRenderTarget function; I get result 5126, after setupFrameBuffer( renderTarget.__webglFramebuffer, renderTarget, _gl.TEXTURE_2D );
if(glType === 5126) if( _gl.checkFramebufferStatus(_gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != _gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
alert("You bronser doesn't support" + "FLOAT as the color attachment to an FBO"); And I get no alert, is that means I use the gl.Float collectly?